# How can I use CSS to separate numbers in my application with commas every 3 digits?

Tags: css, sass

There are many numbers in my application and I want separate them with commas every 3 digits by CSS or SCSS.

I haven't found a desired result on Google.
Can anyone help me on this please?

Like:

```html
<span class="number"> 1234567.89 </span>
```

result:

```html
<span class="number"> 1,234,567.89 </span>
```

Comment: Why do you specifically want to use CSS for this?  Seems like the wrong tool for the job.  What language are you using to display this data?  It should have number formatting functionality.  Or if the data is just in the HTML then just modify it directly.  Or maybe use JavaScript as the page loads.

Comment: Typically whatever put that number there (php, JS, python, whatever) would be responsible for formatting the number properly (from a floating point into a string with commas). CSS itself doesn't have a facility to do so as far as I'm aware.

Comment: @David At first, I thought it would be more complicated to use JavaScript for handling,  because there are a lot of positions involved in the application, and I believed that it would be more cumbersome to make changes. If I were to use CSS, I could simply use ctrl+c and ctrl+v without having to edit more content.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you can use javascript you can use `toLocaleString function`

```
the function: 1234567.89.toLocaleString()

result: '1,234,567.89'
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try the following code

```js
const number = document.querySelector('.number');

const formattedNumber = parseFloat(number.textContent).toLocaleString('en');
number.innerText = formattedNumber;
```

```css
.number::after {
  content: attr(data-number);
}
```

```html
<span class="number">1234567.89</span>
```